# Alternative to one-hot encoding for output to a model when vocabulary size is very large

Tags: nlp, keras, language-model

I was following [this blog](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-word-level-neural-language-model-in-keras/). In it he talks about how to build a language model in keras. He shows how to build a simple model in keras.

> After separating, we need to one hot encode the output word. This means converting it from an integer to a vector of 0 values, one for each word in the vocabulary, with a 1 to indicate the specific word at the index of the words integer value.
>
> This is so that the model learns to predict the probability distribution for the next word and the ground truth from which to learn from is 0 for all words except the actual word that comes next.
>
> Keras provides the to_categorical() that can be used to one hot encode the output words for each input-output sequence pair.

He uses the following:

`y = to_categorical(y, num_classes=vocab_size)`

In his case, the vocabulary size is manageable. I am working with vocabulary having size > 100 million. I guess I should not use a one-hot encoding for the output `y` as done by him. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Not sure it is implemented in Keras, but you might be interested in Hierarchical Softmax (some info in this [blog post](http://ruder.io/word-embeddings-softmax/) by Sebasian Ruder).

Comment: Just yout of curiosity, how can you possibly have 100M vocabulary? And seconding @mcoav, you should really think about defining the objective function for such a monstrosity.